# Regex for numbers only (no spaces or special chars) using ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have an input field that should only be valid if it contains only digits and no special characters and no spaces.  I am using ng-pattern in angular to validate the input.

I have tried using:

```
/^\d+$/

/^\d*$/

/^[0-9]+$/
```

These work to prevent special characters and letters, but do nothing about the spaces.  Does anyone know a regex that would consider spaces an invalid character?  I am trying to avoid preventing the input using keyCode.

I apologize if there's already a thread for this.  I found many similar ones but nothing that helped with the spaces.

EDIT:
Even if the regex is supposed to prevent spaces normally, it is does not seem to be working with ng-pattern:

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" placeholder="(1234567890)" />
```

Is still returning the `ng-valid-pattern` class on the input if I type a space.

Comment: Your regex does **not** allow spaces. See https://regex101.com/r/nM1lY8/1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/63mwL/

Comment: ever figured this out? I'm battling with similar problem, I guess it has to do with angulars ng-pattern not returning false when a space is present in the front of the input. I've got an ng-pattern="/^\\+?[0-9]{6,29}$/"
but it still shows as valid even if I start the input with a whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern should work: /^\d+$/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this pattern /^[0-9]{0,}$/ https://regex101.com/r/bT2oO0/1

Comment: it passes for a completely null string